# Datetimepicker and smalldatetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code in C#:

```
label3.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString(); 
DateTime vencim = dateTimePicker1.Value; 
DataTable llenar3 = minaf.cargrid3(vencim);
BindingSource forwo = new BindingSource();
forwo.DataSource = llenar3;
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = llenar3;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

cargrid3 is this :

```
DataTable rcargaP = new DataTable();
SqlConnection abre1 = Tconex.GetConnection();
SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand llena5 = new SqlCommand("vencedata", abre1);
SqlParameter para1 = new SqlParameter("@venci", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
para1.Value = vence; llena5.Parameters.Add(para1);
llena5.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da3.SelectCommand = llena5;
da3.Fill(rcargaP);
return rcargaP;
```

and the procedure is this   :

```
alter proc vencedata (@venci datetime)as
select   conta,vencimento,pagamento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor 
from financeiro where vencimento >= @venci 
order by vencimento desc
```

the datetimepicker works, the proc works if I write in SQL Studio:

```
vencedata '01/31/2013'
```

the procedure vencedata only works in this format

```
vencedata '03/28/2013' (mm/dd/yyyy)
```

but the when i try

```
vencedata '28/03/2013'(dd/mm/yyyy)
```

i have try too this :

```
alter proc vencedata (@inicio smalldatetime/*,@final smalldatetime*/)as
select idconta,vencimento,pagamento,historico,original,formpagto,planoconta,clifor 
from financeiro where vencimento >= convert (varchar, @inicio,101)
```

a dont work.

Comment: You haven't shown where `vence` comes from at all... it's very hard to help you with a confusing question like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the date in string in the correct format, then pass it as parameter.

Try this.

```
para1.Value = String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", vence);
```

I hope this help you.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that vence is a string that hold the dateTimePicker1 selected date, you can try this :

```
para1.Value = vence.ToString("MM/DD/AAAA");
```

Comment: this line dont work para1.Value = vence.ToString("MM/DD/AAAA");